# Replace Null Values in Arraylist

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

i'm trying to replace null values in my arrayList but I get exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have tried different way :

```
Data.replaceAll(s -> s.replaceAll(" null", ""));
```

And :

```
for(int x = 0; x < Data.size(); x++)
          {
                if(Data.get(x).equals("null") == true)
                {
                    Data.set(x, "");
                }
          }
```

And :

```
for(int x = 0; x < Data.size(); x++)
          {
                if(Data.get(x).equals(null) == true)
                {
                    Data.set(x, "");
                }
          }
```

but an exception is throw `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Here is an exemple of my arrayList:

```
[0050568D6268, null, A001, A, T3, Principal, COL - Test, 4-Lock, Com. On Stage, Social, RDC, null, null, null, null, -1, null, -1, 0, -1, 99, 53]
```

I'm looking for any help thanks.

Comment: `null` and `"null"` are two very different things.

Comment: I tried null and "null"

Comment: Note that when asking about exceptions you should post the entire stacktrace and mark the mentioned lines in the code you've posted.

Comment: I'm using Talend so the stacktrace is like this : Exception in component tJava_3 (LOTS_ACTIF_CREMAJ)
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at genio.lots_actif_cremaj_0_1.LOTS_ACTIF_CREMAJ.lambda$0(LOTS_ACTIF_CREMAJ.java:2158)
 at java.util.ArrayList.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
 at genio.lots_actif_cremaj_0_1.LOTS_ACTIF_CREMAJ.tJava_3Process(LOTS_ACTIF_CREMAJ.java:2158)
 at genio.lots_actif_cremaj_0_1.LOTS_ACTIF_CREMAJ.tDBInput_6Process(LOTS_ACTIF_CREMAJ.java:1969)

Comment: Why do you think `Data.get(x).equals(null)` would not throw an exception when that entry is `nul`? Since when can someone call a method like `.equals` on a null object?

Comment: You understand the difference between having the value **null** in a list, and a string that is "null"?

Comment: On an other program I did this : 

i'm trying to replace null values in my arrayList but I get exception

java.lang.NullPointerException

I have tried different way and this :

Data.replaceAll(s -> s.replaceAll(" null", ""));  and worked perfectly, I don't understand why it's not working with this arrayList. In my other arrayList the first value is null does it matter?

Comment: @GhostCat of course but I tried all the solutions that went through me :)

Comment: @TomI thought it could work like that, I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this line you are comparing the value at position `x` with the String `null` and not "with a null value":

```
if(Data.get(x).equals("null") == true)
```

Replace this comparison by:

```
if(Data.get(x) == null)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! I accept the solution. An idea why Data.replaceAll(s -> s.replaceAll(null, ""));throws an exception ? Because I use it exactly like this on an other program and it worked.

Comment: it's throwing an exception because you are trying to call `replaceAll` on a null object when you call `s.replaceAll`

Comment: you should do what @rdas suggested in his answer: `Data.replaceAll(s -> Objects.isNull(s) ? "" : s);`

Comment: Yes but what I don't get is it's working on an other arraylist with mixing null values and string values.

Answer (score 5):

The values in your list seem to be actual `null`s and not strings with `"null"`. 
You can replace these with `""` by:

```
data.replaceAll(t -> Objects.isNull(t) ? "" : t);
```

You can remove them with:

```
data.removeIf(Objects::isNull)
```

Comment: I don't want to remove it I want to replace it with empty string.

Comment: @PandaRasta Added to the answer

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to use `map()` here:

```
// given list data
data = data.stream()
    .map(s -> Objects.isNull(s) ? "" : s)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This would return a list identical to the input, except with all `null` values replaced by empty string.

Comment: You could also use `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` to just exclude the null elements if you don't need to replace them with some default

Comment: @JonK Yes, but my understanding of the OP is that he wants to replace and retain the originally `null` values.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Exactly

Answer (score 2):

We can not call any method on a null object, that is the reason why you get a NullPointerException.

Below line is throwing NullPointerException because calling `equals` method on null object is not allowed in Java.

```
Data.get(x).equals("null")
```

So replacing above with below will solve the issue.

```
Data.get(x) == null
```

Also, there is no need for the extra comparison with `== true`.